# Why is there a shortcut error on my Inno Setup Compiler installer?

Tags: inno-setup

I seem to have a problem with compiling my games.

I usually compile my games and put it in a backup drive but there seems to be a problem. When I install the game, it seems like it won't work:

[image: Empty file that's supposed to be a shortcut]

[image: completely empty]

Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
#define MyAppName "The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth -ZteamDL-"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ZteamDL"
#define MyAppURL "google.com"
#define MyAppExeName "isaac.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{75BE97EF-4424-46EC-B0C5-6E2F696A6AF3}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=C:\Program Files (x86)\ZteamDL\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth -ZteamDL-
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\alero\Desktop\Randoms\zteam.txt
; Remove the following line to run in administrative install mode (install for all users.)
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed=dialog
OutputDir=C:\Users\alero\Desktop\bi
OutputBaseFilename=The Binding of Isaac Rebirth -ZteamDL-
SetupIconFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\ZteamDL\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth\issacicon.ico
Password=ZteamDL
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ZteamDL\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth\isaac.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ZteamDL\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: The shortcut filename cannot contain the `:` character.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not correct:

Symbol **{#MyAppName}** is not defined.

When I define this symbol the script is working fine (ALL users mode, Create desktop shortcut is checked).

Comment: appname is defined